# should i use Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to create a .Net 3.5 targeted, WPF Application?

Tags: c#

i want to use Visual C# 2010 Express to create a .Net Framework 3.5 using WPF Application- this is due to the comfort that 2010 version gives to its user... (me)

So should I use version 2010 to create a WPF Application in .Net Framework 3.5? if yes, than how do i do that?

Thanks,
Din

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target a previous version of the .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2010 (and 2008), for more info, see the [MSDN How To article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Creating your assembly like this is just fine, if you are not yet comfortable working the the new .Net revision.  You can always retarget to .Net 4.0 later if you want to, and rewrite any code that could benefit from new additions to the Framework or language.

In corporate environments, it's not uncommon for older versions of .Net to be the desktop standard, and in that case you would have to target the specific version of the framework.